# fazer um include de uma biblioteca fora da pasta de bibliotecas

Tags: c++, biblioteca, include

Como faço pra incluir uma biblioteca que não esteja na minha pasta de bibliotecas no C++?

Eu sei que a diretiva do `#include` com `<>` pode fazer o include do arquivo que não esteja na mesma pasta, mas se eu possuir várias pastas com uma biblioteca com mesmo nome, me pergunto se ele não confundiria a biblioteca que eu criei, com outras bibliotecas de outros projetos do C++ que eu também criei no meu PC.

Gostaria de saber se não tem uma opção para ele procurar em uma pasta fora da raiz sem que eu precise colocar todo o caminho de onde ela esta,usando `""`, ou ele conseguirá encontrar minha biblioteca com `<>` mesmo que eu tenha outras bibliotecas em outras pastas com o mesmo nome?

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Isso pode ser configurado na sua IDE, por exemplo, no visual studio você pode procurar nas opções as pastas 'include' e colocar/digitar a sua pasta lá.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar uma parte do nome do caminho da seguinte forma:

```
#include <projeto1/meuHeader.h>
#include <projeto2/meuHeader.h>
```

Porém o caminho desses projetos precisará estar na lista de includes e na lista de bibliotecas para linkagem. Essa parte final depende de como está trabalhando, pode ser no Visual Studio/Eclipse diretamente, no Makefile ou no CMakeList.